# How to add 3 integer value and verify in protractor?

Tags: javascript, protractor

My code :

```
element.all(by.css('span.badge.ng-binding')).get(0).getText().then(function(first) {
             console.log(first);

             element.all(by.css('span.badge.ng-binding')).get(1).getText().then(function (second) {
                 console.log(second);

                 element.all(by.css('span.badge.ng-binding')).get(2).getText().then(function (third) {
                     console.log(third);
```

Using this code am getting 3 integer value like :

```
1001
587
368
```

I declared a variable like this :

var sum = 3000;

Problem:
 I have to add all three integer values and have to verify with the "sum".

In this case it should return fail.

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer

```
expect(parseInt(first) + parseInt(second) + parseInt(third)).toEqual(sum);
```